# create event in apps script not receiving spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I cannot get this to work and i am lost, i have searched and searched for an answer and i cannot see what is causing this to fail, i am pulling data from a spreadsheet and trying to add as an event to a google calendar-
 freezes at getcal()event, says cannot find method createalldayevent(string,string)-line71

i have modified the code to this but still...

```
\\function to get required information from sheets 
and set as script properties to use in later functions//

function getsheet(getsheet){


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar Data");
var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("call form");
var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Job Summary Sheet");

var getval = sheet2.getRange("A1:A").getValues();

var getlast = getval.filter(String).length;

var finval = sheet2.getRange(getlast, 1).getValues().toString(); 
var finval2 = sheet1.getRange(getlast, 2).getValues().toString();
var finval3 = sheet1.getRange(getlast, 5).getValues().toString();
var finval4 = sheet3.getRange(getlast, 6).getValues().toString(); 
var finval5 = sheet3.getRange(getlast, 12).getValues().toString();


var title = finval + '-' + finval4 ;
var startTime =  finval3;
var endTime =  finval3;
var location = finval2;
var description = finval5;

PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('title', title);
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('startTime', startTime); 
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('endTime', endTime);
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('location', location);
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('description',    description);


Logger.log(title);
Logger.log(startTime);
Logger.log(endTime);
Logger.log(location);
Logger.log(startTime);
Logger.log(description);

} 

 \\\\function getsheet() works correctly-
 --gets last row of each required sheet and sets information as script   properties////

function getcal2(){
getsheet();
var title = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('title');
var Date = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('startTime');
var endTime =     PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('endTime');
var location = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('location');
var description = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('description');


////freezes at event2/////


var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('xxxxxo@group.calendar.google.com');
var event2 =event.createAllDayEvent(title,Date
);


Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId()); 
Logger.log(title);
Logger.log(startTime);
Logger.log(endTime);
Logger.log(location);
Logger.log(startTime);
Logger.log(description);

}

\\\fails at event2-cannot find method-i am new to this
```

but your help is really giving alot of understanding...I appreciate it!////

Comment: It looks to me that in `var getlast = getval.filter(String).length;` String is undefined. Please checkout [mcve]. By the way, could be better ways to find the last row but it will depend on the structure of your spreadsheet.

Comment: i have done your suggestions, maybe they will help you, thanks

Comment: What I mean in the first part of my previous comment is that your script have to declare the variable `String` before the line `var getlast = getval.filter(String).length;`

Comment: @Rubén, i tried changing it and it broke the code, which i am not sure why that would, but it pulls the info correctly as is, so i will work on that, could that break the createevent() call, that is my major issue..Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line 3 you're calling the method [createAllDayEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle-date) when the variables `title` and `startTime` are `undefined`, just move the line  3 (where you define the `var event`) after the line `var description = finval5` or [call your function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions) getsheet() with those arguments.

**EDIT:**

You're using the method [createAllDayEvent(title, date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle-date) the two arguments that it receives are:

1. `title` needs to be a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) so make sure the value you're getting from the Spreadsheet is a String.
2. `date` in **needs** to be a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples) so make sure the value in the spreadsheet is in a valid date format, if you edit the cell you must see a calendar, if not go to the menu Format > Number > Date

Google Sheets stores data depending on the value of the cell, the values may be of type `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, or `String` (Empty cells will return an empty String). When these values are used bye the Scripts, Apps Script treats them as the appropriate data type in JavaScript.

**EDIT 2:**

As I mentioned above the method [createAllDayEvent(title, date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle-date) receives in the second argument a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples), and now you're using [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to store the date values, but this service store the values as Strings, so now before you use your date to create the event, you need to transform it to Date object, something like this:

```
var date = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('startTime');
var dateObj = new Date(date); // create the Date Object
var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('xxxxxo@group.calendar.google.com');
var event2 = event.createAllDayEvent(title, dateObj);
```

Comment: i changed as you sugggested, and learned something , although still need help, thank you very much, i appreciate it, i placed the updated script below original

Comment: ,i changed as you suggested, although createevent still doesnt work, i also modified script per comments above, Thank You!!

Comment: I edited my answer, but I see you totally changed the code xD Let me edit it again.

Answer (score 0):

It may be in your format.

Try this snippet for testing:

```
function setValues() {

var values = {};
values['title'] = 'Lunch Meeting';
values['description'] = 'Lunch Meeting';
return values; 
}

function addEvent(){
var data = setValues();
var calendarID = 'primary';
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID)
var event = calendar.createAllDayEvent(data.title,
new Date('August 22, 2016'),
{description: data.title});
Logger.log(data);
}
```

I used `primary` as a testing calendar ID. Then used `setValues()` to form the details for the Calendar Event (You can use the sheets to get the value then assign it to var values). Kindly check the document of [`createAllDayEvent(title, date, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEvent(String,Date,Object)) and [google apps script calendar sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) for some code implementation and correct code format.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Guys-
Problem Is Solved!!!
Two issues-
1-although at first i had the proper format, i was not calling "date" as a [date],
2-i was not calling any function for add event, just variables.
fix-
convert "date" to [date]
removed event 2 as variable and just called "event" create event()
and ran separate

```
 function run(){
  getsheet();
   getcal2();
  }
```